# Order SATA ports on mobo

Tags: motherboard, sata

I have a Dell T3500 with one (1) hard drive. I want to add a 2nd SATA hard drive. I'm running Win 7 64-bit in a non RAID configuration.

My C:\ drive is connected to the SATA-2 port on the mobo.

I installed the 2nd drive and connected it to the SATA-0 on the mobo.

My question is: does this matter? Do I have to order them nicely (SATA-0, SATA-1, etc.) or not at all?

Answer (score -1):

Probably the bios will start looking for the operating system on the 2nd drive first. But otherwise it won't matter.

Comment: Yeah, it did. :-) But I changed the boot sequence so that solved it. So basically what you're saying is it's not really required to order them nicely, however, it does make sense. Right?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Correctly, it is no problem. When having another operating system that you do not use often which is on the 1st drive it could be irritating. The computer will boot that OS. But if you don't have an OS on the first drive it doesn't matter.